# how to use variables and import files in symfony yaml config component

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, yaml

I use the config component of symfony on a project and I need tu use the same value in various sections of my yml configuration file.

Does someone know how to reproduce the behavior of the symfony configuration.yml using the config component?

I would like to import configuration files:

```
imports:
  - { resource: otherfile.yml }
```

or to declare variables:

```
myvar: value
othervar: %myvar%
```

Comment: What does reproduce means to you? If you want to reuse scalar values you can use `parameters`. If you want to reuse a bunch of settings, just create a configuration for it, let symfony parse it and hand it over to a service with some getters.

Comment: I only use the config and yaml components of symfony, not the entire framework. So I wonder how to reproduce the behavior of the symfony kernel while it load the symfony config files.

Comment: This does not happen in the Kernel itself but in the `DependencyInjection` folder (per Bundle) the `*Extension.php` loads the `Configuration` object which generates the NodeTree.

Comment: ok, so is there a symfony component that allow this nice behavior outside of a symfony project?

Answer (score 3):

The Symfony Config component do not have this feature built in. Defining and resolving imports and parameters in config files is part of the DependencyInjection component, namely its FileLoader class (Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\FileLoader).

If you don't want to add the whole DependencyInjection component as a dependency, your best approach is to simply extend the Config component's own FileLoader class, override the load() method, read in the configuration, look for the "imports" child elements and call "$this->import()" on the file paths referenced therein.
Then read everything under the "parameters" key, iterate over all your config keys and replace any occurrences of previously found parameters with their values.

Example:

```
public function load($resource, $type = null)
{
  // ...
  // Load your config data as usual. It's assumed that
  // the configuration is now a multidimensional array
  // named $content
  // Load the imports:
  if (isset($content['imports'])) {
      foreach ($content['imports'] as $import) {
          $extraContent = $this->import($import['resource']);
          $content = array_replace_recursive($extraContent, $content);
      }
  }
  // Store the parameters:
  if (isset($content['parameters'])) {
      foreach ($content['parameters'] as $param) {
          foreach ($param as $key => $value) {
              $this->_parameters[$key] = $value;
          }
      }
  }
  // iterate over all configuration keys and substitute
  // placeholders with parameter values:
  array_walk_recursive(
      $content,
      function(&$val, $key) {
          $matches = null;
          preg_match('/\%(.*?)\%/', $val, $matches);
          $param = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : false;
          if ($param) {
              if (isset($this->_parameters[$param])) {
                  $val = str_replace("%$param%", $this->_parameters[$param], $val);
              }
          }
      }
  );    
  // And you're done. From here on, proceed as usual
  // (like, validate content against a ConfigurationInterface
  // implementation
  // ...
}
```

Be warned: The example code is very much abbreviated, contains no error checking and has not been tested in this short form - but it does contain all the steps neccessary and I hope it can point you in the right direction.

It's also recommended to look at the Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\FileLoader class and see how it's done there (ignore all the resource registration stuff).

Answer (score 2):

A little hack of Markus Wolff code:

```
class FileLoader extends \Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader
{
    private $_parameters;

    public function addParameter($k, $v)
    {
        $this->_parameters[$k] = $v;
    }

    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        $resource = $this->getLocator()->locate($resource, null, true);
        $content = \Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($resource));

        if (isset($content['imports'])) {
            foreach ($content['imports'] as $import) {
                $extraContent = $this->import($import['resource']);
                $content = array_replace_recursive($extraContent, $content);
            }
        }

        if (isset($content['parameters'])) {
            foreach ($content['parameters'] as $key => $value) {
                $this->_parameters[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        array_walk_recursive(
            $content,
            function (&$val) {
                $matches = null;
                preg_match_all('/\%(.*?)\%/', $val, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
                if ($matches) {
                    foreach ($matches as $match) {
                        if ($param = isset($match[1]) ? $match[1] : false) {
                            if (isset($this->_parameters[$param])) {
                                $val = str_replace("%$param%", $this->_parameters[$param], $val);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        return $content;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return is_string($resource) && 'yml' === pathinfo($resource, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is some untested code for you:

```
<?php
// parse yaml to an array
$parser = new \Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser();
$configs = $parser->parse(\file_get_contents('config.yml'));

// your config tree
$configuration = new Configuration();

// processor reading the config from the array according to the Configuration NodeTree
$processor = new Processor();
$result = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

// you can be 100% sure, that your $result array has the attributes you set in Configuration
```

The processor should validate the configuration for you and throw exceptions. But you can also just parse YAML and access the array directly

Comment: would be nice to know what use statements to use for these classes